# Populate Managed Schema - Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: solr

**Sitecore 9.0 update 2**

**Solr 6.6.2 and 6.6.3** (same result on both, both supported: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)

I'm facing an issue when I "Populate Managed Schema" from control panel. My `managed-schema` gets updated 99.9% correctly. The 0.1% that is incorrect is that the `uniqueKey` element value generates as `id`:

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

A *correct* `managed-schema` generates as:

```
<uniqueKey>_uniqueid</uniqueKey>
```

The rest of the file generates properly. While I *can* manually change the `uniqueKey` element value, I would prefer to get to the bottom of my issue (as I'm attempting to automate things, with this being a key step).

When I run "Populate Managed Schema", the modal indicates `[Success]`. However, when I rebuild a particular index I am greeted with this error:

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">2</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name="msg">Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

Prior to this exception being thrown, the index rebuild progress modal progresses as expected, e.g. "Added 1,000 items to index".

As stated above, I've tested this on Solr 6.6.2 and 6.6.3 with the same result each time. It appears the issue is on the Sitecore side of things. No issues were reported during the installation of Sitecore and the rest of the pieces (Content Editor, Exp Editor, etc.) work properly.

#### Edit/Update

Comparison of my automated web root with a working 9.0.2 copy shows no discernable differences.

Comment: It randomly began working. Some combination of restarting Solr or something else. Will reproduce and post results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is a result of not reading the fine-print with regards to configuring Solr for Sitecore

From Sitecore:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/solr_managed_schemas
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr

Both of these links walk through the prerequisites needed prior to executing "Populate Managed Schema". They also both make the assumption that your Solr instance is currently **NOT** running. Notice this step on both links...

> 4. Start Solr.

Solr must be started after the prerequisite schema changes are made. However, if Solr is currently running, it must be *restarted* (i.e. restart the Solr service). This will properly reload the core configurations into memory. From there the "Populate Managed Schema" action will execute correctly.

### General Steps to Resolve

1. On the Solr server, navigate to the folder that contains your cores, e.g. `C:\Solr\solr-6.6.2\server\solr`
2. In the `configsets` folder, copy the `basic_configs` config set either to A) a new config set and then reference it from each core, or B) copy the `conf` folder to each core individually
3. Make the two required schema changes:

   1. `Set the value in <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey> to _uniqueid.`
   2. `In the fields section, add field configuration for _uniqueid:
      <field name="_uniqueid" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>`
4. **RESTART SOLR/SOLR SERVICE**
5. Execute Populate Manged Schemas from Sitecore Control Panel

> Note: These steps are not relevant for any xdb indexes. These indexes use the out-of-the-box configsets

Comment: Thanks @jrap this worked for me.Field with name _uniqueid is already populated for me in field configuration.So i need not add the step 2 in 3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default implementation of `ISchemaPopulateHelper` (`Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.PopulateSolrSchema.SchemaPopulateHelper`)?

Over the last year I've found a few issues in the default implementation. Take a look at that class and compare it with your Solr managed schema. In `GetAllFields()` a list of add/remove/replace fields are generated. Oddly, this is an XML representation that is later converted into JSON, that in turn is sent to the Solr REST API.

Are you perhaps having an `id` field in your schema, so that adding the `_uniqueid` field (from `GetAddFields()`) fails? See if `GetRemoveFields` contains removal of your existing `id` field.

Regardless, it could be worth doing your own implementation of `ISchemaPopulateHelper` in order to fix some language stemming issues etc. More details here: https://mikael.com/2018/01/working-with-content-search-and-solr-in-sitecore-9/

Comment: This was a completely vanilla install. No customizations.